# UIView added as Overlay In AVPlayer won't fire any action when touched

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, avplayer

**Issue**:
I have an AVPlayer where I overlaid a View with a nested view that fires an action when pressed (GADBannerView). However, when pressed, it doesn't do anything nor It registers touches.

**Test Code**

```
let adBanner: UIView = {
 let view = UIView()
 view.addSubview(GADBannerAlreadyInstantiatedView())
return view
}()


AVPC = AVPlayerViewController()
AVPC!.player = self.contentPlayer
AVPC.addSubView(AdBanner)
```

**Expected**
I should be sent to watch the ad in a new window, but instead, it doesn't do anything. Only the AVPlayer controls react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `adBanner` has zero size (because you gave it no `frame`). A subview of a view with zero size, like your gad banner view, can be seen but cannot be touched.

Comment: Adding a frame isn't solving the problem.

Comment: I don’t know what else you’ve done. I’m responding just to the code you gave.

Comment: Sorry If I sounded rude, I'm really grateful you helped!

Comment: And of course I don’t see you giving your GADBannerAlreadyInstantiatedView any size either, but then you didn’t show any of that code